# cannot fetch related entity data from findAll()

Tags: symfony, select, doctrine, find, relational-database

I get problem when load related data using findAll (I try to load attribute username from related entity) :

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyAwesomeBundle:Employee');

$employees = $repository->findAll();
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    echo $employee->getUser()->getUsername();
}
die("not work -_-");
```

error message : FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object in...

but my other code using findOne is working correctly :

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyAwesomeBundle:Employee');
$employee = $repository->findOneByCode($code);
die("".$employee->getUser()->getUsername());
```

my question is how to load $employee->getUser()->getUsername() inside foreach if I use findAll to load all data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `Employee` in database that has no `User` associated with it.

When loading just one, you are loading one who has User associated, but when looping over all, you stumble upon one who doesn't and at that point, your code fails.

Solution: find `Employee` without associated `User` and remove it, or associate a `User` with it.